# How to print type of primitive variables in Java

Tags: java, variables, type-conversion, primitive

I want know that the type of variable in my class for example:

```
int x=1;  
char c=5;
System.out.println(x+c);// out put is 6
```

but i want to know the type of `x+c`, whether it belongs to `integer` or `character`? and also want to print the result in console.

Is there any method to find the type? please help me with best answers.

Comment: "but i want to know the type of x+c, whether it belongs to integer or character" The type is `int`.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there any method to find the type?

Well, from a research point of view you could read the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html). In particular, [section 15.18.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) explains how the `+` operator works.

If you want to do this just from an execution-time point of view, there are two options:

- You could autobox, and then see what the boxed type is:

  ```
  Object o = x + c;
  System.out.println(o.getClass()); // java.lang.Integer
  ```
- You could write a method which is overloaded for *all* primitive types, and see which the compiler picks:

  ```
  System.out.println(getCompileTimePrimitiveClass(x + c));
  ...
  private static Class getCompileTimePrimitiveClass(int x)
  {
      return int.class;
  }

  private static Class getCompileTimePrimitiveClass(char x)
  {
      return char.class;
  }

  private static Class getCompileTimePrimitiveClass(byte x)
  {
      return byte.class;
  }

  // etc
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int x= 1;
    char c = 5; // '\u0005'
    char c1=6; // '\u0006'
    //char c2=e;// ->Error
    char c3 = 'a';

    Object o,o1,o3;
    o=c;
    System.out.println("c var is " + c + " " + o.getClass() ); // java.lang.Character
    // out : c var is  class java.lang.Character

    o=x+c;
    o1=x+c1;
   // o+=x+c3; -> error operator + cannot be applied here



    System.out.println("x + c = " + o +
            " type of primitive is " + o.getClass().getTypeName().substring( 10,o.getClass().getName().length() ) );  // out : -> x + c = 6 type of primitive is Integer

    System.out.println("x + c1 = " + o1 +
            " type of primitive is " + o1.getClass().getTypeName().substring( 10,o1.getClass().getName().length() ) ); // also Integer class`enter code here`
```

If someone wants to use some methods of Object class

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find the type of (x+c) as below.

```
int x=1;  
char c=5;
String type = ((Object)(x+c)).getClass().getSimpleName();
System.out.println(type);
```

Comment: Why do we need the explicit casting to Object tho

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you could use one of the below methods to get the type of an object in Java.

```
String myText = "example"; // non-primitive data type
    
System.out.println(myText.getClass().getSimpleName()); // String
System.out.println(myText.getClass().getName()); // java.lang.String
```

Note that: String is a non-primitive type, so it is actually an object. However, primitive types are not objects. They consume less memory and can be accessed faster. So, you can not call the `getClass` method. In this case, you can first cast the variable to object and then call necessary methods.

```
int myVar = 10; // primitive data type

System.out.println((Object)myVar).getClass().getSimpleName()); // Integer
System.out.println((Object)myVar).getClass().getName()); // java.lang.Integer
```